# Watir-Webdriver - Checking for enabled linke

Tags: ruby, methods, automation, watir

I am having trouble checking if a link is enabled for automation testing.

I have the following code but it throws an error:

```
if @browser.link(:xpath,'//*[@id="aBreakDown"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a').enabled?
    print_red("User can import a new activity")
else 
    print_green("User cannot import a new activity")    
end
```

I get the following error:

> undefined method `enabled?' for #
>   (NoMetho dError)

Is there a way around this??

Comment: First at all, add html of this tag, please

Comment: Watir isn't support such method as `enabled?` for links but, if you add HTML - we will think about alternative

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply, html as requested:

<div class="col-lg-5">
                <a ng-disabled="job.IsLocked" ng-show="jobReport.ActivityBreakdownStartTime" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="importActivities()">Import activities from another job</a>
            </div>

Comment: `job.IsLocked` - it's mean that link disabled, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, let's try someth about:

```
if @browser.link(:xpath,'//*[@id="aBreakDown"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/a').attribute_value("ng-disabled") == "job.IsLocked"
    print_green("User cannot import a new activity")
else 
    print_red("User can import a new activity")    
end
```